# apache ext filter not working

Tags: apache-2.2

following the docs at :http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html

Cant get a simple filter to replace text on the page...

```
ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=input cmd="/bin/sed s/works/sorta/ig"
        AddOutputFilter fixtext htm html
        SetOutputFilter fixtext

        <Location />
                SetOutputFilter fixtext
        </Location>

        <Directory />
                ExtFilterOptions LogStderr DebugLevel=0
        </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax:

```
ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=output intype=text/html \
                cmd="/bin/sed s/works/asdf/ig"

        <Location />
                SetOutputFilter fixtext
        </Location>
```

If anyone is trying to apply ExtFilter rules to Reverse Proxy sites, there is a bug:

http://objectmix.com/apache/706472-proxypass-extfilter.html

Comment: guys, can anyone confirm?  this is bug: http://objectmix.com/apache/706472-proxypass-extfilter.html